# Symmetric group- find the elements of the set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to find the center of $S_n$.

$Z(S_n)=\{ c \in S_n: cg=gc , \forall g \in S_n\}$.

Every $c\in S_n$ can be written as a product of  transpositions, $$c = \prod_{i = 1}^r (1\, m_i)$$ for some $r$ and some sequence $(m_i)_{1\leqslant i \leqslant r}$, right?

If so, how could we prove this?

Doesn't this imply that we can consider $g$ to be of the form $(1 \ m)$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$?
Because if we want to pick for example $g=(1 2) (2 3)$ then $(2 3)$ can be included at the product of transpositions that represents c, or am I wrong?

Then since $g$ is of the form $(1 m)$ it holds that $g=g^{-1}$.

So $cg=gc \Leftrightarrow c=gcg$.

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g=(1 m)$.

Also let $c=(a_1 a_2 \dots a_n)$.

Is it right so far? Do we have to distinguish now cases for $c$, i.e. if it contains $1$ and $m$, one of them or none of them?

Comment: In your "how can we prove this", what statement are you actually referring to?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That every $c \in S_n$ can be written as $\prod_{i=1}^r (1 \ m_i)$.

Answer (score 1):

All the non abelian symmetric groups have trivial center.
For proving that the symmetric group $S_n$ is centerless for $n \ge 3$ is enough [this](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/symn-is-centerless-if-n-is-at-least-3/) easy lemma that essentially is a combinatorial idea.

Answer (score 0):

One should note that every element in $S_n$ can be written as a product of transpositions, although not necessarily in the form that you have written.

Anyhow, one thing that may help understand the center (or lack thereof) for $S_n$ is the following. For simplicity, let's just pick the $n$-cycle $(1, 2, \ldots, n) \in S_n$ and some random $\sigma \in S_n$. Then we can write its conjugate as
$$
\sigma \cdot (1, \ldots, n) \cdot \sigma^{-1} = \big(\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \ldots, \sigma(n)\big)
$$
From this you should be able to determine with some care the center of $S_n$.

Comment: In fact the permutations can be written in the form specified (not that this is particularly useful most of the time).

Comment: We have $$\sigma \cdot (1, \ldots, n) \cdot \sigma^{-1} = \big(\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \ldots, \sigma(n)\big) \\ \Rightarrow \sigma \cdot (1, \ldots, n) \cdot \sigma^{-1} \cdot \sigma = \big(\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \ldots, \sigma(n)\big)\cdot \sigma \\ \Rightarrow \sigma \cdot (1, \ldots, n)  = \big(\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \ldots, \sigma(n)\big)\cdot \sigma $$ 

Suppose that $\sigma$ is not the identity.

Comment: Then $$\big (\sigma (1), \sigma (2), \dots , \sigma (n)\big )\neq \big (1,2,\dots , n\big )$$ 

So we have that $$\sigma \cdot (1, \ldots, n)  \neq \big (1,\dots , n\big )\cdot \sigma$$ 

So when $\sigma$ is not the identity then $\sigma \notin Z(S_n)$.

Comment: Suppose that $\sigma$ is the identity. 

Then $$\big ( \sigma (1), \sigma (2), \dots , \sigma (n)\big ) = \big (1,2,\dots , n\big )$$ 


So we have that $$\sigma \cdot (1, \ldots, n)  = \big (1,\dots , n\big )\cdot \sigma$$ 

So when $\sigma$ is the identity then $\sigma \in Z(S_n)$. 

This means that $Z(S_n)=\{\text{id}\}$. 

Is it right? Or could I improve something?

Comment: You do have to be a little bit more careful; your argument, if correct, would imply that $S_2$ has only a trivial center; however, $S_2$ is abelian! That is the correct idea, however, but one should be a bit more careful. It may be easier in this case to be *less* general than you are, in fact.